# Flutter BottomAppBar has different color, than the udjusted one

Tags: flutter

I created a Flutter BottomAppBar and an icon in it. The page background color, the BottomAppBar's color and the icon color is the same: Colors.white. But the BottomAppBar is always darker, why?

```
BottomAppBar(
      height: 50,
      color: Colors.white,
      child: Row(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
              width: 30,
              child: IconButton(
                constraints: const BoxConstraints(),
                style: const ButtonStyle(
                  tapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
                ),
                padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                icon: Icon(Icons.archive, color: Colors.white, size: 30),
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The slightly tinted color comes from the [`surfaceTintColor`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/BottomAppBar/surfaceTintColor.html) property. Change it to transparent to remove the effect.

```dart
BottomAppBar(
  surfaceTintColor: Colors.transparent,
  // ...
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is due to material3 support in the latest versions of flutter.

You can disable material3 by adding a `ThemeData` on your `MaterialApp`:

```
MaterialApp(
    home: MyWidget(),
    theme: ThemeData(useMaterial3: false),
  )
```

Or, if you still want to support material3. you can specifically set the theme:

```dart
 theme: ThemeData(
          bottomAppBarTheme: const BottomAppBarTheme(
            color: Colors.white,
            elevation: 0.0,
          ),
        )
```

Result (in both cases)

[image]